# Sub-pixel rendering in OpenGL - accuracy issue

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I need to generate a few series of test images for a photogrammetric application. 
These should contain simple objects (disks, rectangles, etc) with a very precisely known position.

Considering a 8bit grayscale image of a black rectangle on white background, a smallest observable displacement (after interpolation) should be 1/256 pixel, as there are 256 possible intensity levels of each pixel.

I decided to use OpenGL (with python + pyglet) to render such images, as later on I will have to render more complicated (3d scene, stereo image pairs)

Unfortunately, the best accuracy I have achieved is around pixel/10, the full intensity depth is not used.

Is it possible to do better, ideally - achieving full 1/256pixel accuracy? Any hints on how to do that, please?

sample code, generating images of a partial disk, moved 0.01 pixel more in each frame

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

config = pyglet.gl.Config(width = 800, height = 600, sample_buffers=1, samples=16)
window = pyglet.window.Window(config=config, resizable=True) 
window.set_size(800, 600)

printScreenNr = 0

@window.event
def on_draw():
     global printScreenNr
     window.clear()
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

     glLoadIdentity()
     glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
     glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

     glTranslated(200, 200,0)

     circleQuad = gluNewQuadric()
     glTranslated(200+(printScreenNr*0.01), 0, 0)
     gluPartialDisk(circleQuad, 0, 50, 500, 500, 0, 180)

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho (0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED

@window.event
def on_text(text):
    global printScreenNr
    if(text == "p"):
        pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save('photo'+str(printScreenNr)+'.tiff')
        printScreenNr += 1

pyglet.app.run()
```

(the code above is using gluPartialDisk, but I have tested the issue also using quadrangles, results' accuracy did not differ)

Comment: Have you tried using a 32-bit color depth? The reason I say this is that 32-bit paths are the most used and hence most-maintained code-paths in graphics drivers nowadays. If this works, you can then perform a high quality color depth rescale afterward.

Comment: tried that, but did not change the results...
still, thank you

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do this is to scale the image by a factor. If you scale the image by 4.0, then 16 original pixels will be merged into one target pixel which gives you 16 shades of gray when scaling a pure B&W image.

But there is a catch which probably explains your problem. If you have this:

```
  ...#####
  ...#####
  ...#####
  ...#####
```

(left: white, right: black filled rectangle), then you have 12 white and 4 black pixels that contribute to a single output pixel. To get 1 black pixel, the input would need to be this:

```
  ....####
  ....####
  ....####
  ...#####
```

See? Even though the black box leaks only one pixel into the white space, it does so four times. So to make sure your subpixel rendering code works, you need to look at single pixels or corners, not at the edges.

Comment: Rendering a (way) bigger image would be a solution, but I think the size of the screen is a limitation? So it will not help much

About the other part of your answer, I'm not sure if i understand correctly...

if image has been scaled 4x (in each direction), that gives 4 possible shades when observing an edge (and 16 when observing a point)

but still, it should be somehow possible to generate an edge positioned with full-depth accuracy

Comment: How? the edge has only four different positions, so you can get only 4 out of 16 shades.

Comment: please correct me if I'm still wrong 

Let's suppose the image has been scaled by 256 factor.
An edge would have 256 positions, and a point: 256^2(which would be rounded)

I dont know, if such thing is possible to do in OpenGL (in this case performance is not an issue), 
but I think images meeting these requirements are generally possible to generate. My question is just: how to do that..

Comment: You probably want to scale by 16 (16x16 = 256). Render into an off-screen texture and then scale the texture onto a rectangle that exactly fits the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the offscreen texture suggestion. However I do not want to scale by 16 - I need accuracy of at least 0.01 pixel in _each_ direction, so this is not enough. Maximum texture size is limited, so I dont know if it is possible in OpenGL

Comment: [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) should be able to create images of (almost) any size. If you create the original image as B/W (1 bit per pixel), you should be able to make it really huge.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using orthogonal projection, GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT might have impact on rendering accuracy. At least I vaguely remember glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); fixing some gaps on my orthogonally projected scene many years ago.

Comment: Thank you, added that, did not change the results at the moment, but maybe will be needed in future 3d mode